# RxJS - pausing an Observable until second Observable completes,

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I have a scenario where 1 observable listens for events, which should then fire another asynchrounous event, and wait before it runs the next item in the source Observable.

The first observable can be triggered much faster than the the async event, and it must wait for the async event to complete before it takes another item from the 1st observable.

So.. essentially I  need to set up a 'queue' from the first observable (as I cant lose the data from source 1)

Source 2 should take 1 item at a time from the queue, run it, remove the item from the queue, and go onto the next item in the queue .

```
src1-  --ev1---ev2---ev3----ev4---ev5--ev6---
src2-  --ev1------------ev2-------------ev3--------ev4-------ev5------ev6
--------------async-----------async---------async------async------asyc
```

I was looking at the RX docs and it seems that pausibleBuffered could be a solution but I noticed it has been removed in RX5, which is what I am using.  Can someone give advice as the right way to accomplish this ?
Thanks!

Comment: As it stands, your diagram is unclear, though I commend you for writing one in the first place. That did help a bit, while not being completely clear. In any case, for the worded question, it seems like this is a lossless back-pressure issue. One problem with lossless backpressure is that you will eventually run out of memory (or any other related finite resource) if your src1 lasts too long. Otherwise you can refer to this : https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1542

Comment: I think this is a very similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469442/pattern-for-observables-that-includes-acknowledgement/46475877#46475877

Comment: thanks for the comments, and yea I probably didn't explain it as well as I should. 
I was able to use combineLatest on the src1 and src2 observables. Checking the status of the queue and if there was still an async action going on. Easier than I had expected :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mergeScan` to run async operations one by one because it needs the previous async operation’s result to run an async operation.

```
const src2 = src1.mergeScan((_, value) => doSomething(value));
```

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeScan