# Rxjs Subscribing until another event happens

Tags: rxjs

I am new to Rxjs and am trying to implement the following workflow in it:

1. User clicks on a menu item that triggers an HTTP request
2. Before the response has arrived, the user clicks on a second request
3. The subscription to the first request is ended and a subscription to the second request is started

   ```
   // The code below sits inside the onClick event of my menu
   var callAction = function(someParameters) {
               return Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
                   var subscribed = true;
                   myHttpApi.someActionCall(someParameters).then(
                       (data: any) => {
                           if (subscribed) {
                               // Send data to the client
                               observer.next(data);
                               // Immediately complete the sequence
                               observer.complete();
                           }


                       }).catch((err: any) => {
                           if (subscribed) {
                               // Inform the client that an error occurred.
                               observer.error(ex);
                           }

                       }
                   );
                   return function () {
                       subscribed = false;
                   }
               });
           };
   ```

The observer is further defined below:

```
var observer = {
                // onNext in RxJS 4
                next: function (data) {
                    // Do what you need to do in the interface
                },
                // onError in RxJS 4
                error: function (err) {
                    // Handle the error in the interface
                },
                // onComplete in RxJS 4
                complete: function () {
                    //console.log("The asynchronous operation has completed.");
                }
            };

            let subscription = callAction(somParameters).subscribe(observer);
```

How do I now go about implementing #3, whereby the subscription to the first request is ended and a subscription to the new request (in this example, the same block of code is executed for different menu options and therefore different requests based on the parameters) is started?

Comment: Look at example 2: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html and use `Rx.Observable.from` to wrap the promise, but be aware that promises are not cancellable. You might want to consider using an [RxJS AJAX observable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41288856/6680611) instead.

Comment: You probably looking at a queuing pattern like this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469442/pattern-for-observables-that-includes-acknowledgement/46472309#46472309

Comment: @FanCheung The pattern here is different -- instead of waiting for the previous one to complete, I want the previous one to be aborted and the next one to be the one that we are subscribed to. How might that be done?

Comment: @cartant Thank you! switchmap might be just what I need -- will try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking up the steps into discrete functions,

```
// Inner observable, calls the API
const callAction$ = function(someParameters) {
  return Observable.fromPromise(
    myHttpApi.someActionCall(someParameters)
  ) 
}

// Outer observable, controls the click chain
const click$ = new Subject();
click$.switchMap(clickParams => {
  return callAction$(clickParams)
})
.subscribe(
  result => console.log('Result: ', result), 
  err => console.log('Error: ', err.message)
)

// Handler function, called from menu
const handleClick = function(clickParams) {
  click$.next(clickParams)
}
```

Working example [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/xPKpVM)